# Metadata version mismatch for module C:/xampp/htdocs//node_modules/angular2-flash-messages/module/index.d.ts

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I use angular 4 and i founderror when i install angular2-flash-messages via npm with this commande:

> npm install angular2-flash-messages --save

I founed this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3KYa.png)

i update package.json with nom update and this is code package.json:

```
{
          "name": "employeesang4",
          "version": "0.0.0",
          "license": "MIT",
          "scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "start": "ng serve",
            "build": "ng build",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "ng lint",
            "e2e": "ng e2e"
          },
          "private": true,
          "dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
            "angular2-flash-messages": "^2.0.5",
            "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
            "core-js": "^2.4.1",
            "firebase": "^4.8.0",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
            "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "@angular/cli": "1.4.0",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
            "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
            "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
            "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
            "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
            "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
            "karma": "~1.7.0",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
            "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
            "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
            "protractor": "~5.1.2",
            "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
            "tslint": "~5.3.2",
            "typescript": "~2.3.3"
          }
        }
```

also I inject module angular2-flash-messages in appModule and in component when I use but also I have error

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and what ended up working out for me was going into your package.json file, and setting the version to `^1.0.5`
Then go and do `npm update`